# Интерфейс WinForms при подключении через RDP зависает

Tags: c#, winforms, rdp

При подключении через RDP программа WinForms зависает.
Данная проблема описана в статье: https://ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang
Однако, данные из этой статьи лишь незначительно смогли мне помочь.

Причина в том, что я произвожу обновление элементов интерфейса из фонового потока через control.Invoke() или через контекст синхронизации SynchronizationContext, используя следующий статический метод:

```
public static void UIThread(SynchronizationContext uiContext, SendOrPostCallback code, object state=null, UIThreadMethod method=UIThreadMethod.async)
        {
            if (method==UIThreadMethod.sync)
                //код выполняется синхронно, а исключения передаются в вызывающий поток, а не в поток UI
                uiContext.Send(code, state);
            else
                //код выполняется асинхронно, а исключения передаются в UI поток
                uiContext.Post(code, state);
        }
```

Контекст синхронизации я захватываю в начале MainForm_Load() и записываю в статическое поле:

```
public static UIContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

а затем, вызываю обновление контролов в параллельных потоках, например:

```
UIThread(UIContext, obj=>
            {
                pbIndicator.Image = AksSoft.Properties.Resources.ok_small;
                llRememberRefresh.Text = $"обновить";
                llRememberRefresh.Enabled = true;
            });
```

Всё работает нормально, до тех пор, пока я не подключаюсь через RDP.

Выяснил, что в момент подключения через RDP в программе срабатывает событие SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged, которое вызывает перерисовку контролов интерфейса и это вызывает зависание.

Помогли следующие шаги и статья https://exceptionshub.com/windows-form-application-freeze-randomly-when-run-overnight.html.

1. в файле Program.cs, до вызова Application.Run(new MainForm()) просто добавил подписку на событие:

```
SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged;
```

обработчик события следующий:

```
static void SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(object sender, UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //здесь ничего, просто пустой блок (!)
        }
```

2. Далее, в обработчике MainForm_Load() главного окна программы MainForm() делаю посылку системного сообщения:

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Environment"), SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, MSG_TIMEOUT, out RESULT);
```

чтобы его отправить, требуется добавить следующий код, до обработчика MainForm_Load():

```
[Flags]
public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
    SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
    SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
const uint WM_WININICHANGE = 0x001A;
const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE;
const int MSG_TIMEOUT = 15000;
```

Обязательная отправка данного сообщения нужна для того, чтобы приложение принудительно начало обрабатывать пустой SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(), а не тот, который вызывает системный код, приводящий к зависанию.

После запуска программы будет незначительная задержка отклика интерфейса, т.е. интерфейс отображается, но "оживает" и становится кликабельным через несколько секунд, однако, это рабочее решение, позволяющие избежать уродливого беспричинного зависания!

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Пробовали вместо `SynchronizationContext` использовать `Control.Invoke()`/`Control.BeginInvoke()`? Без вот этих вот костылей.

Comment: Еще ни в коем случае нельзя делать `сontext.Send()` если `сontext == SynchronizationContext.Current`, это 100% дедлок.

Comment: Кстати, какая версия .NET? У меня есть Winforms приложение, тоже с многопоточкой и контекстами, в RDP не зависает, я вообще до вашего поста не знал, что такая проблема в принципе существует.

Comment: `HWND_BROADCAST` не понял, зачем это сообщение отправлять всем окнам, вы можете взять просто `SendMessage` и отправить это сообщение себе, то есть на Hwnd своей главной формы. Эффект будет тот же, только не придется ждать 15 секунд до таймаута, если какое-то окно не обработало сообщение. И последнее: подписывание на `UserPreferenceChanged` никак не блокирует и не заменяет вызов системного кода. Это логически невозможно, это ж просто делегат. Вплоть до того что компилятор просто выбросит этот пустой метод из сборки, и строчку с подписыванием удалит, как бесполезную, и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю, что уделили время данной проблеме, которая, к сожалению, действительно существует. Версия .NET 4.8.2 Использую SynchronizationContext, а не Control.Invoke() по той причине, что синтаксис получается значительно более удобным, особенно, если обновляется сразу множество контролов. Спасибо, теперь буду использовать вместо 'HWND_BROADCAST' this.Handle. Кстати, я сам не понимаю, как может обычная подписка на событие что-то изменить, но факт остаётся фактом, нужно просто подписаться на UserPreferenceChanged, по видимому в недрах .NET что-то переключается и форма перестаёт зависать!)

Comment: @aepot Да, Ваш ответ очень помог! Большое спасибо за конструктивные правки!

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Comment: @aepot Точно! Я ещё не освоился здесь как пользователь, который может что-то комментировать и ставить. Мой рейтинг долгое время был слишком низкий, поэтому я этого никогда не мог делать ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно ждать когда все окна обработаюти сообщение, которое нужно только вам, отправляйте его только себе.

```
// не делайте Win API методы public, для безопасности
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

```
void SendSettingsChange()
{
    IntPtr text = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Environment");
    try
    {
        const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange
        if (SendMessage(IntPtr.Zero, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, text) != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(text); // неуправляемую память сборщик мусора сам не почистит
    }
}
```